# Can C# return connection string on SQL connection error?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I don't want people to get connection string on error - example:

```
Try
{
    // Some SQL code that fails
}
Catch (Exception sl)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error - " + sl)
}
```

Is there a possibility that they could see connection string in exception sl? How can I avoid it? Also, they need to see error message, but without connection string.

I am using SQL Server.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes exception could contain sensitive information in them, not just connection string but even other info. As a good practice, you need to catch all exceptions at the trust boundary, log them and then throw another exception with a friendly message to inform the client (caller). Remember that exceptions are a way to let callers know that due to exceptional unanticipated reasons you could not fulfill the request. If the caller can do something and try again, you may tell them so. Otherwise you just have to admit the failure and fault is yours and you apologize and will look into it.

Comment: Who are `they` here? Here if `they` means the application users, then yes they can not see the connection string while using your program until the program exposes the information somehow. If you handle the exception properly and do not show anything sensitive in messagebox

Comment: It is not good practice to catch base `Exception` anyway. If you catch `SqlException`first, the `ToString()` method of it will not reveal the connection string, as you can see in its implementation here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlException.cs,8d89751a51b25f41. But this is not the point. If you are showing the exception message to the end user, it should not contain any technical information at all (but should in development / integration environments). 1. Catch / 2. Logg with Full Details / 3. Show a "technical failure" user friendly exception

Comment: @chetan I think even the default exception dialogue will show the info so the user will see it. But, if the exception is swallowed by the application, then the users won't see it. But then again you're trusting the application which is also just another user so no difference.

Comment: Thanks for all sugestions. They are users. I will think about making it more user friendly.